# Slice Notation with Comma , Numpy - Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I came across something like this:

```
list(training[:,0])
```

I searched and learned that these are being used at Numpy Arrays. But still didn't understand the logic behind this. The part where it says `[:,0]` what does that mean? Which parts does it choose from the training array?

```
training = np.array(training)
#create train and test lists.
train_x = list(training[:,0])
train_y = list(training[:,1])
print("Training data created")
```

Comment: What parts of the code *do* you understand? Have you read or done a basic numpy tutorial on slicing? Since you have working code, what parts of its behavior and result are not clear to you? Do you know what `[:]` and `[0]` would mean for a regular python list?

Comment: Yes. I wasn't sure about what  ' : ' alone would mean before the comma and what these transactions would give as an output. But thanks to comments i get it now

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the numpy array

```
import numpy as np

myArr = np.array([[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9]])
```

For any general array `arr[a:b, c:d]` means that we have to consider rows from index a to index b-1 and columns from index c to index d-1

`myArr[1:2, 1:2]` means that we have to consider rows from index 1 to index 2-1(i.e 1) and columns from index 1 to 2-1(i.e 1) or in other words, we have the element at row 1 and column 1 which is `5` in our case

Remember that row index starts from 0 and the column index also starts from 0

`myArr[:,1:3]` here you can see that ':' implies that we have to consider all rows and columns from index 1 to (3-1) i.e. 2

in this case our output will be

```
array([[2, 3],
   [5, 6],
   [8, 9]])
```

See we got all the rows using ':' in the first position and we got 2nd (index 1) and 3rd (index 2) column

Likewise using ':' in columns side will fetch you all the columns

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped really a lot to me.This left no question marks on my mind!

Comment: Pleased to help you

Answer (score 0):

Let us take a closer look at each line of our code.

```
training = np.array(training)
train_x = list(training[:,0])
train_y = list(training[:,1])
```

This indicates that `training`is of shape `(N, M)` and `M=2` since there is x and y data. The slicing command `:` selects all entries. Thus, in this case `[:, 0]` selects/returns all values of the first column, while `[:, 1]` selects all entries of the second column (for a 2D array).